# How to declare and subscribe to queryParams in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'll compose this problem into two perspectives that are interconnected. The user's perspective and the developer's perspective.

The user's perspective:

When "Edit Server" is clicked, it should allow the user to edit the server. That's not what's happening though. I'll provide 2 pictures that demonstrate this problem.

(1)
[image]

(2)
[image]

As you can see, I do not want this to happen.

Developer's perspective:

The developer (me) is new to routing, but will walk you through the code. Basically, When I subscribe to queryParams, I end up with an empty object. I would assume that it's because

```js
this.router.navigate(['edit', 
{ queryParams: {allowEdit: this.server.id == 3 ? '1' : '0'}}],
{relativeTo: this.route})
```

is not working. Now, why is it not working, perhaps it has to do with when it's called? I'll provide the relevant code on this question on Stack Overflow and I'll provide the repo in case anyone needs to see the full project.

App Module Code

```
// the appropiate paths
  // Before, ':id' and ':id/edit' were siblings, I just changed it so 'edit' is a now the grandchild of
  // 'servers' For some reason, EditComponent is not even loading, its ngOnInIt is not working. 
  {
    path: 'servers',
    component: ServersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ServerComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'edit',
            component: EditServerComponent
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Servers HTML Template:

```html
<div class="list-group">
      <!-- 
          Routerlink points to the server component NOT 'edit-server' component
        -->
      <a
        [routerLink] = "['/servers', server.id]"
        href="#"
        class="list-group-item"
        *ngFor="let server of servers">
        {{ server.name }}
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- There's other irrelevant code in between -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Server HTML Template:

```html
<!-- The display is just for what is displayed, is it 'edit-server' or the 'server' to be displayed. This is not an issue
     However, this code should be relatively easy to understand. The most important part is the button -->
<div [ngSwitch]="display">
<div *ngSwitchDefault>
    <h5>{{ server.name }}</h5>
<p>Server status is {{ server.status }}</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEdit()">Edit Server</button>
</div>

<div *ngSwitchCase="1">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit-Server TS:

```js
server: {id: number, name: string, status: string};
  serverName = '';
  serverStatus = '';
  allowEdit: boolean
  id: number

  constructor(private serversService: ServersService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.snapshot.queryParams
    this.route.snapshot.fragment
    // We navigated to EditServerComponent, yet the params object is empty and so it always goes to false
    // since an empty object is not equal to '1'.
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.allowEdit = params['allowEdit'] == '1' ? true : false
    })

    // I am 80% sure that the code below has nothing to do with the problem
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = +params['id']
    })

    this.server = this.serversService.getServer(this.id);
    this.serverName = this.server.name;
    this.serverStatus = this.server.status;
  }

  onUpdateServer() {
    this.serversService.updateServer(this.server.id, {name: this.serverName, status: this.serverStatus});
  }

}
```

Edit Server Template:

```html
<h4 *ngIf="!allowEdit">No editing the server!</h4>
<div *ngIf="allowEdit">
   <!-- Since, allowEdit is always false, this inside code will never run -->
</div>
```

How can I solve the mystery to why the params object is empty?

Here's the whole repo in case anyone wants to see what's going on:

https://github.com/yousefmarey12/TestingwithAngular.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is a little problem with your router.navigate() call inside onEdit method

The first parameter should be the route you need to access, as string item into an array. Then, the second parameter an object with your query params and relativeTo prop. I.E.:

```
this.router.navigate(['edit'], { queryParams: {allowEdit: this.server.id == 3 ? '1' : '0'}, relativeTo: this.route});
```

There you will see all your data in queryParms subscription.